# Spock how to mock a method of the same class for a Java class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock

I have a Java class

```
class MyClass {
  void methodA() {  
         //something 
  }
  void methodB() { 
         //something else 
  }
}
```

I wanted to unit test methodA but methodA depends on methodB. I have gone through the spock documentation but I am not able to find how to handle this scenario. What should I do?

**Note** 
I was not able to find an answer for this so I am self-answering this question on stackoverflow which is allowed [as per stackoverlfow's self-answering policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Added this note to avoid confusion for those who are not aware of the self-answering policy so do not remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually documented in the spock docs, see the section [partial mocks](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#PartialMocks).

```
// this is now the object under specification, not a collaborator
def persister = Spy(MessagePersister) {
  // stub a call on the same object
  isPersistable(_) >> true
}

when:
persister.receive("msg")

then:
// demand a call on the same object
1 * persister.persist("msg")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a similar thing when spying on already instantiated object?

Comment: @schatten you can use an instance to create a spy, but note that the instance is only used as template, i.e., all the internal state is copied and a new spy instance is created. So if some other classes still use the old instance you won't see anything.

Comment: What I meant to ask: is there a way to spy on instance and provide a closure to do partial stubbing.

Comment: No, you can't use a closure (in Spock 1.x), you have to use the normal way of defining interactions. With 2.x you can, but it is still in milestone stage.

Answer (score 3):

This is a way without mocking where you override the needed method:

```
def "your spock test"() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
        @Override
        void methodB() { 
            // do something related to this test
        }    
    }

    expect:
    //whatever you want to do
    myClass.methodA()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution of this is to do the following in your tests

```
def "your spock test"() {
        MyClass myClass = Mock(MyClass)
        myClass.methodA() >> {
            callRealMethod()
        }
        myClass.methodB() >> {
            //your mocking logic
        }
    expect:
        //whatever you want to do
    }
```

callRealMethod allows you to call the actual implementation when you are mocking via spock.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings answer is more appropriate in your scenario!

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink this solution a bit, because what you are doing here is [you are testing mock instead of a real object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45458925/2194470). I wouldn't mock anything in this class and I would treat it as a unit for simplicity. If `methodB` represents different unit scope then `methodA` then maybe this is a good starting point for refactoring this class and extracting responsibilities encapsulated in `methodB` to a separate class injected to the one you are trying to test. Then mocking this injected class has much more sense in my opinion. But firstly always ask yourself why you want to mock and if there is any better alternative (mocking should be your last option worth considering).